# How to unit test file_put_contents() with file read/write permitions

Tags: php, file, testing, permissions

I am writing a unit test for a function that throws an exception when file_put_contents fails to write to a file. 
I need to make sure that the exception is thrown when file_put_contents is unsuccessful. 
Is there a way in php to make a file temporarily unwritable or unreadable?

I tried with chmod but it does not seem to work in Windows (XAMPP).

Comment: Reference a file in a folder that doesn't exist?

Comment: Or if you're using phpunit for your tests, use [vfsStream](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream)

Comment: Or set chmod accordingly?

Comment: Are you testing the conditions under which file_put_contents can fail or the fact that file_put_contents may fail? In the latter case, you can try th technique described for example here: http://marcelog.github.io/articles/php_mock_global_functions_for_unit_tests_with_phpunit.html

Comment: file_get_contents(uniqid()); file_put_contents('/', 'foo'); unlink(uniqid())